# Indefinite integral of $\frac1{1-x^a}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there any known result for the following indefinite integral for any $a>0$ ?
$$ \int \frac{1}{1-x^a}\,\mathrm{d}x $$

For $a=1 ~\& ~2$, I could get expressions via different methods(change of variables and fraction separation respectively). But can we tell anything for any general $a$?

Thanks in advance for any help in this regard!

Comment: $$I=x_2F_1(1,1/a,1+1/a,x^a).$$It can be simplified when $a\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: "When a= 0" the integrand doesn't exist!  So how did you get any result?

Comment: I guess it was meant to be "For $a = 1~\&~2\ldots$"

Comment: No closed form in terms of elementary functions from Galois?

Comment: @user247327 Sorry, it was for $a=1$ and $a=2$.

Comment: Is $a$ an arbitrary real? For rational $a = m/n$, you can write a sum over the roots of $x^m - 1$ with explicit coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the $n$-th derivative of $z^\alpha$ is given by $$D^nz^\alpha=p(\alpha,n)z^{\alpha-n}$$ Where $p(\alpha,n)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(\alpha-k+1)$, we have $$D^nz^{\alpha}|_{z=1}=p(\alpha,n)$$
Because of this, we get the Taylor series for $z^\alpha$:
$$z^\alpha=\sum_{n\geq 0}p(\alpha,n)\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}$$
Plugging in $z=1-x^a$, and $\alpha=-1$, we get
$$\frac{1}{1-x^a}=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{p(-1,n)}{n!}(1-x^a-1)^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x^a}=\sum_{n\geq0}(-1)^n p(-1,n)\frac{x^{an}}{n!}$$
Which can be integrated term-by-term.

Comment: $(\alpha)_n$ in the definition of the hypergeometric function stands for the rising factorial.

Comment: @Maxim I'm pretty sure that's not the case, but I'll change it anyway.

Comment: I appreciate you taking note of my comment, but the point is that your $p(\alpha, n)$ is the falling factorial. Because of that, $z^\alpha \neq {_1F_0}(\alpha; ; z - 1)$. You should check any source such as Wikipedia for the definition of ${_pF_q}$.

Comment: @Maxim I know perfectly well what $_pF_q$ is, yet there seems to be some misinformation here. The page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function says that $(a)_n$ is the rising factorial, yet the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials says that $(a)_n$ is the falling factorial. And both pages give different definitions of $_2F_1$, and thus different definitions of $_pF_q$. I will update my answer as soon as I figure out the truth.

Comment: @Maxim Update: I grouchily admit that you're right, so I'll change my answer.

Comment: The result is the geometric progression $\sum_{n \geq 0} x^{a n}$, as expected. Integrating term by term shows how we can arrive at a hypergeometric function. The ratio of two consecutive terms will be
$$\left. \frac {x^{a (n + 1) + 1}} {a (n + 1) + 1} \middle/
 \frac {x^{a n + 1}} {a n + 1} \right. =
\frac {n + \frac 1 a} {n + \frac {a + 1} a} x^a,$$
while (with rising factorials)
$$\left. \frac {(\alpha)_{n + 1}} {(\beta)_{n + 1}} \middle/
 \frac {(\alpha)_n} {(\beta)_n} \right. =
\frac {n + \alpha} {n + \beta}.$$

Answer (score 0):

When $a$ is a positive integer, $1-x^a$ always factors into real linear and quadratic factors.  Then you can use fraction separation, and it ends up a sum of logarithms and arc-tangents. Ask Wolfram Alpha for the first few.